# How to detect is xemacs was opened with no window system

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

there are portions of my .emacs file that I would like to behave differently depending if emacs was opened in a terminal (ie, `emacs -nw`) or in a window. How does one go about detecting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my FSF .emacs, I have code like this:

```
(if (null window-system)
    (global-set-key "\C-h" 'delete-backward-char))
```

It looks like this works under XEmacs as well, though the preferred XEmacs way is to use the `console-type` function instead. Do `M-x describe-function` on `console-type` for details.